# Can't pass out 3.5k req/s on AWS Varnish

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, varnish

I'm currently trying to deploy a Varnish on AWS.
This varnish is intended to cache 1 file from S3 (only one file, less than 10kb), with a hit rate of 10k+ requests/s

I've deployed my server on a m4.large instance (2vCPU / 8Gb Ram).
I've launch a performance test from a Jmeter cluster but i can't pass out 3.5k req/s, and it's seems a little bit low.

when i check my system metrics, i can't find any bottleneck (CPU/Ram/IOPS/Network).

My varnish command line :

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -T 127.0.0.1:6082 -t 86400 -u varnish -g varnish -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,1G -p idle_send_timeout=0 -p thread_pool_min=500 -p timeout_linger=100000 -p thread_pool_add_delay=2 -P /var/run/varnish.pid
```

OS : AWS AMI - 2017.09.1

Varnish version : varnishd (varnish-4.0.5 revision 07eff4c29)

Here is my param.show

```
-----------------------------
Varnish Cache CLI 1.0
-----------------------------
Linux,4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
varnish-4.0.5 revision 07eff4c29

Type 'help' for command list.
Type 'quit' to close CLI session.

varnish> param.show
200        
acceptor_sleep_decay       0.9 (default)
acceptor_sleep_incr        0.001 [seconds] (default)
acceptor_sleep_max         0.050 [seconds] (default)
auto_restart               on [bool] (default)
ban_dups                   on [bool] (default)
ban_lurker_age             60.000 [seconds] (default)
ban_lurker_batch           1000 (default)
ban_lurker_sleep           0.010 [seconds] (default)
between_bytes_timeout      60.000 [seconds] (default)
busyobj_worker_cache       off [bool] (default)
cc_command                 "exec gcc -std=gnu99  -O2 -g -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Wall -Werror -pthread -fpic -shared -Wl,-x -o %o %s" (default)
cli_buffer                 8k [bytes] (default)
cli_limit                  48k [bytes] (default)
cli_timeout                60.000 [seconds] (default)
clock_skew                 10 [seconds] (default)
connect_timeout            3.500 [seconds] (default)
critbit_cooloff            180.000 [seconds] (default)
debug                      none (default)
default_grace              10.000 [seconds] (default)
default_keep               0.000 [seconds] (default)
default_ttl                86400.000 [seconds]
feature                    none (default)
fetch_chunksize            16k [bytes] (default)
fetch_maxchunksize         0.25G [bytes] (default)
first_byte_timeout         60.000 [seconds] (default)
group                      varnish (497)
group_cc                   <not set> (default)
gzip_buffer                32k [bytes] (default)
gzip_level                 6 (default)
gzip_memlevel              8 (default)
http_gzip_support          on [bool] (default)
http_max_hdr               64 [header lines] (default)
http_range_support         on [bool] (default)
http_req_hdr_len           8k [bytes] (default)
http_req_size              32k [bytes] (default)
http_resp_hdr_len          8k [bytes] (default)
http_resp_size             32k [bytes] (default)
idle_send_timeout          0.000 [seconds]
listen_address             :6081
listen_depth               1024 [connections] (default)
lru_interval               2.000 [seconds] (default)
max_esi_depth              5 [levels] (default)
max_restarts               4 [restarts] (default)
max_retries                4 [retries] (default)
nuke_limit                 50 [allocations] (default)
pcre_match_limit           10000 (default)
pcre_match_limit_recursion 10000 (default)
ping_interval              3 [seconds] (default)
pipe_timeout               60.000 [seconds] (default)
pool_req                   10,100,10 (default)
pool_sess                  10,100,10 (default)
pool_vbc                   10,100,10 (default)
pool_vbo                   10,100,10 (default)
prefer_ipv6                off [bool] (default)
rush_exponent              3 [requests per request] (default)
send_timeout               600.000 [seconds] (default)
session_max                100000 [sessions] (default)
shm_reclen                 255b [bytes] (default)
shortlived                 10.000 [seconds] (default)
sigsegv_handler            off [bool] (default)
syslog_cli_traffic         on [bool] (default)
tcp_keepalive_intvl        75.000 [seconds] (default)
tcp_keepalive_probes       9 [probes] (default)
tcp_keepalive_time         7200.000 [seconds] (default)
thread_pool_add_delay      2.000 [seconds]
thread_pool_destroy_delay  1.000 [seconds] (default)
thread_pool_fail_delay     0.200 [seconds] (default)
thread_pool_max            5000 [threads] (default)
thread_pool_min            500 [threads]
thread_pool_stack          48k [bytes] (default)
thread_pool_timeout        300.000 [seconds] (default)
thread_pools               2 [pools] (default)
thread_queue_limit         20 (default)
thread_stats_rate          10 [requests] (default)
timeout_idle               5.000 [seconds] (default)
timeout_linger             100000.000 [seconds]
timeout_req                2.000 [seconds] (default)
user                       varnish (498)
vcc_allow_inline_c         off [bool] (default)
vcc_err_unref              on [bool] (default)
vcc_unsafe_path            on [bool] (default)
vcl_dir                    /etc/varnish (default)
vmod_dir                   /usr/lib64/varnish/vmods (default)
vsl_buffer                 4k [bytes] (default)
vsl_mask                   -VCL_trace,-WorkThread,-Hash (default)
vsl_reclen                 255b [bytes] (default)
vsl_space                  80M [bytes] (default)
vsm_space                  1M [bytes] (default)
waiter                     epoll (possible values: epoll, poll) (default)
workspace_backend          64k [bytes] (default)
workspace_client           64k [bytes] (default)
workspace_session          384b [bytes] (default)
workspace_thread           2k [bytes] (default)
```

My VCL File :

```
vcl 4.0;
backend default
{
  .host = "******.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
  .port = "80";
}
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.Host = "******.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
  set req.http.Date = now;
  unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
set beresp.do_gzip = true;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
unset resp.http.set-cookie;
}
```

Have you any idea of how can i tune my varnish to obtain a better througput ?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why do you want to cache file from S3 in Varnish?

Comment: To limit S3 requests and reduce download time, and I've to assume a custom DNS record in https/http. CloudFront is too expensive for this use case.

Comment: Well...Okay, that might be okay, though I'm still interested why do you have 10k req/s for a single file. Please add if the ec2 is behind a load balancer or if it's public.

Comment: And please add screenshots or all relevant CW metrics.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.